# failed test FsmoCheck - A Time Server could not be located

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

When doing an FSMO check on my PDC (BEZADC01) I am getting a time server error:

```
    C:\Windows\system32>dcdiag /test:FSMOcheck

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = BEZADC01
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: BEZA\BEZADC01
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... BEZADC01 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: BEZA\BEZADC01


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

   Running partition tests on : Schema

   Running partition tests on : Configuration

   Running partition tests on : intra

   Running enterprise tests on : intra.domain.be
      Starting test: FsmoCheck
         Warning: DcGetDcName(TIME_SERVER) call failed, error 1355
         A Time Server could not be located.
         The server holding the PDC role is down.
         Warning: DcGetDcName(GOOD_TIME_SERVER_PREFERRED) call failed, error
         1355
         A Good Time Server could not be located.
         ......................... intra.domain.be failed test FsmoCheck

C:\Windows\system32>
```

However BEZADC01 is synced with NTP

I checked this article: http://clintboessen.blogspot.be/2013/11/the-server-holding-pdc-role-is-down.html

I have enabled the announce flag, and set NTP.

But still no luck :(. How can I resolve this error?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you cycle the time service after making the registry changes that set it as authoritative ?

Comment: I have ran these commands on the PDC:

`net stop w32time w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
net time /setsntp: 
net stop w32time & net start w32time
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:pool.ntp.org /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
w32tm /resync /rediscover
net stop w32time & net start w32time`

I have tun them the PDC only, but that didn't help. I have run them now on all the DC's, and now the dcdiag /test:FSMOcheck succeeds! 
Al tough I don't get why this is. I would suspect that having the PDC NTP settings correct would be correct, as he is the FSMO holder